# How to extract comma separated values in java from string

Tags: java, string

I have a string like:

```
 [comment=null, mapping={client_unique_id=0, email=1, first_name=2, last_name=3, batch_id=4}, recordNumber=2, values=[sdsd, asdsdf.com, jjj, hhh, 24]]
```

Now I need to fetch only   **sdsd, asdsdf.com, jjj, hhh, 24**  from values.
How could I do this?

Comment: try to  use split or Regex

Comment: @XYz Amos   but i need string to split only in values key

Comment: Watch out for the order. If String is produced by a HashMap - the order of its elements is not guaranteed and can change anytime anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Use regex

```
values=\[(.*)\]
```

Then you need to get group 1 from the match. The groups are:

```
0: values=[sdsd, asdsdf.com, jjj, hhh, 24]
1: sdsd, asdsdf.com, jjj, hhh, 24
```

Try this

```
        Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("values=\\[(.*)\\]");
        Matcher matcher = compile.matcher("[comment=null, mapping={client_unique_id=0, email=1, first_name=2, last_name=3, batch_id=4}, recordNumber=2, values=[sdsd, asdsdf.com, jjj, hhh, 24]]");
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return matcher.group(1);
        }
        return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

suppose,

```
str =  "[comment=null, mapping={client_unique_id=0, email=1, first_name=2, last_name=3, batch_id=4}, recordNumber=2, values=[sdsd, asdsdf.com, jjj, hhh, 24]]";
```

to get -- ssdd, asdsdf.com, jjj, hhh, 24 use this --

```
String result = str.split("values=[")[1].split("]")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your string is

```
String str = "sdsd, asdsdf.com, jjj, hhh, 24";
```

And you want to separate this string by comma and generate an array from it, you can do it by

```
String[] strArray = str.split(", ");
```

Now you will get an array of strings like `"sdsd", "asdsdf.com", "jjj", "hhh", "24"`.

Answer (score 0):

Some simple way could be to use the just the functions provided by java.lang.String.  This would do it.

public class StringTest {

```
public String[] getValues(String content, String searchString) {

    // where does my search String start within the content?
    int valuesPosition = content.indexOf(searchString);

    // we have to separate the content, we are looking for
    String values = content.substring(valuesPosition + searchString.length() + 1, content.length() - 2);

    // the split-Method does exactly, what we want and creates an array of our single comma separated fields
    String[] singleValues = values.split(",");
    return singleValues;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    StringTest stringTest = new StringTest();
    String content = "[comment=null, mapping={client_unique_id=0, email=1, first_name=2, last_name=3, batch_id=4}, recordNumber=2, values=[sdsd, asdsdf.com, jjj, hhh, 24]]";
    String searchString = "values=";

    String v[] = stringTest.getValues(content, searchString);

    System.out.println("it contains " + v.length + " Elements:");
    for (String v1 : v) {

        // by the trim()- method, we eliminate white spaces.
        System.out.println(v1.trim());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you have comma separated String:

```
str = " [comment=null, mapping={client_unique_id=0, email=1, first_name=2, last_name=3, batch_id=4}, recordNumber=2, values=[sdsd, asdsdf.com, jjj, hhh, 24]] ";
```

Step1: remove [] using `string.replaceAll("[[\\]]","");`

Step2:Split it and make it an array of string.

```
String[] strArray = str.split(", ");
```

now get String present at the 7th index you will be having this:

```
String newStr = "values=[sdsd, asdsdf.com, jjj, hhh, 24]";
```

repeat the step 1 to remove "values" and "[]" again you will be having comma separated string.
Follow step 2 and you will be having the values.